# Ksoap2 or Sun WirelessToolKit stubs?

Tags: java, blackberry, ksoap2

I am making a BlackBerry application that sends a byte array of captured audio to a web service. What is the best tool for this -- ksoap2 or using Sun ToolKit to make stubs?

Comment: is this an existing web service with a specification, or are you building both the client and server at the same time?

Comment: Building both the client and the server. The server is also Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought I'd answer this since it's been so long already I went with ksoap2 for my application and I use BaseEncode64 to be able to send the byte[] over to the web service.